# How to trully bind key in python console program in linux?

Tags: python, linux

I'm looking for key binding in python [linux].

My program must catch key 'q' and close correctly.

I found this

```
import curses
stdscr = curses.initscr()
curses.cbreak()
stdscr.keypad(1)

stdscr.addstr(0,10,"Hit 'q' to quit")
stdscr.refresh()

key = ''
while key != ord('q'):
    key = stdscr.getch()
    stdscr.addch(20,25,key)
    stdscr.refresh()
    if key == curses.KEY_UP: 
        stdscr.addstr(2, 20, "Up")
    elif key == curses.KEY_DOWN: 
        stdscr.addstr(3, 20, "Down")

curses.endwin()
```

But it stuck loop, while any key is pressed, my program must work every seconds and catch 'q' in background.

Comment: kinda hard when lines are buffered until the return key is pressed

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
stdscr.nodelay(True)
```

To the beginning of the program. Then getch will always return right away. It'll return -1 if the user hasn't pushed anything since last time you called getch.

Comment: Great. Thanx! Do you know how to do the same without curses? e.g. my program hear signals, ctrl+c send signal to console daemon. ctrl+q should stop correctly daemon.

Comment: @stackterminator, have you looked at the python signal module?

Comment: Not yet, i will, but i do not like curses.